# returning arrays from functions

Tags: php, arrays, function, refactoring

I am trying to refactor some of my code with `arrays` and what I have here is this

```
$body[] = array(
//array stuff part1 here

);

$body[] = array(
//another array stuff part2 here

);

$body[] = array(
//and another array stuff part3 here
);
```

now what I want to do is separate them into functions like this

```
part1();
part2();
part3();
```

and than assign variable to these functions back to the same stop..do I call it like this

```
$body[] = part1();
```

or can I call it like this

```
$body = part1();
$body = part2();
$body = part3();
```

if I do it like this will they override each other ?

Comment: If you have working code you are probably better at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Also I wouldn't create functions just to return arrays.

Comment: `$body[] = part1();` this syntax append at the end of array `$body`. 
`$body = part1();`  this is simple assignment so value of `$body` variable updated.

Comment: `$body = anythign` will overwrite whatever was in `$body` with `anything`. `$body[] = anything` is the equivalent of `array_push()`, and will append the `anything` to the $body array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - yes, they will override each other.
You should do like this:

```
$body[] = part1();
$body[] = part2();
$body[] = part3();
```

or

```
$body = [part1(), part2(), part3()];
```

or find any other approach that will fit your needs